# How to combine shader effects in threejs

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

Coming from the Flash background, I'm used to creating a fragment shader in the following manner:

```
filters = [];

filters.push(new BasicFilter(SomeTexture));
filters.push(new NormalMapFilter(SomeOtherTexture));

myShader = new Shader(filters);
```

As a result, I could combine a number of effects freely and easily without the need of writing a large separate shader each time.

In case of threejs, I noticed that for complex visual effects, a single shader is written, like here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_bumpmap_skin

Is it possible to write e.g. a bump map shader and environment map shader separately and then combine them dynamically when needed? What would be the most proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible directly in three.js. Three creates shaders by passing the shader code as a string directly to a WebGL shader object to compile. There is no mechanism to automatically build complex shaders, you have to write your own. Three.js conveniently adds a couple of uniforms/attributes to the shader, but you have to write what's done with them.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to give your answer an upvote:(. Anyway, guess I'll try to write some sort of shader generator, as in producing a string to compile on the fly.

Comment: Yes you might try to do that. I guess you should be careful especially with the variable names if you plan to merge many pieces of code together, as there is a major potential for conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Effect Composer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/postprocessing/EffectComposer) now to combine shaders

Comment: Isn't Effect Composer is for combining post-process's pass? Not material's shader.